# Nothing happens when I run HTMLdecode on a variable of a dataset

Tags: html, r, encoding, textutils

I want to decode some vectors with HTMLdecode but it does not work in some cases. I read in data from an excel sheet and I want to decode a variable and it does not work. If I manually set up these variable it works for some reason and I really don't have an idea why.

```
library(magrittr)
library(openxlsx)
library(data.table)
library(textutils)

Data.Guests <- read.xlsx("Data/xxx.xlsx") %>% 
  setDT 

HTMLdecode(Data.Guests[, Name]) # does not work, nothing happens
vector <- Data.Guests[, Name]
HTMLdecode(vector) # does not work
HTMLdecode(c("Rübezahl", "Meier")) # does work. "Rübezahl" is one element of the variable
```

This is what `dput(Data.Guests)`  looks like:

```
structure(list(Titel = NA_character_, Vorname = NA_character_, 
    Name = "Rübezahl", Email = NA_character_, Institution = NA_character_, 
    Position = NA_character_, Anrede = "Herr", `Priorität-einladen` = NA_character_, 
    nachrangig = NA_character_, Noch.überlegen = NA_character_, 
    Bemerkung.1 = NA_character_, Salutation = "Sehr geehrter Herr Rübezahl,\n"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002571ef0>)
```

Comment: May you share `dput(Data.Guest)` so your example is reproducible?

Comment: See my edit. Thank you!

Comment: I just `tmp <- HTMLdecode(Data.Guests[, Name])` and worked. Weird. (ver 1.12.0 `data`table` and 0.1-9 `textuitls`)

Comment: When I load the `structure` of the output of `dput` it works for me, too ... Really weird ... Any idea what is the difference between the 'original' and the result of `dput`?

Comment: Are they `identical(Data.GuestsA, Data.GuestsB)`?

Comment: `FALSE`. But I removed the part from `.internal.selfref` before I created the structure.

Comment: Thank you @LocoGris. With `dput` I found a solution that works (see my own answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is my hack now ...
I'm not really satisfied with that but it works ...

```
fil <- file("Data/tmp.r")
dput(Data.Guests, fil)
Text <- readLines(fil)
Text %<>% str_replace(", \\.internal.*", ")")
writeLines(Text, con = fil)
Data.Guests <- dget(fil)
```

With that it works for some reason ...